# ML.NET how to make input model generic?

Tags: ml.net

I have 3 use cases for multiclass classifications and their InputModels are all different as they have different columns and data structures. How can I refactor below method so that it can predict any kinds of InputModels without copying and repeating the method 3 times just to cater for 3 different input data structures?

```
    private List<MulticlassClassificationPrediction> Predict(string modelName, string testDataPath)
    {
        PredictionEngine<InputModel, MulticlassClassificationPrediction> predEngine;

        predEngine = _predEnginePool.GetPredictionEngine(modelName: modelName);

        IDataView dataView = _mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<InputModel>(
                            path: testDataPath,
                            hasHeader: true,
                            separatorChar: ',',
                            allowQuoting: true,
                            allowSparse: false);

        // Use first line of dataset as model input
        // You can replace this with new test data (hardcoded or from end-user application)
        List<InputModel> testDataList = _mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<InputModel>(dataView, false).ToList();

        List<MulticlassClassificationPrediction> predictionList = new List<MulticlassClassificationPrediction>();
        foreach (InputModel testData in testDataList)
        {

            MulticlassClassificationPrediction result = predEngine.Predict(testData);

            predictionList.Add(result);

        }

        return predictionList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, have you had a chance to try something like this?

```
private List<MulticlassClassificationPrediction> Predict<TInputModel>(string modelName, string testDataPath) where TInputModel: class, new()
{
    PredictionEngine<TInputModel, MulticlassClassificationPrediction> predEngine;

    predEngine = _predEnginePool.GetPredictionEngine(modelName: modelName);

    IDataView dataView = _mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<TInputModel>(
                        path: testDataPath,
                        hasHeader: true,
                        separatorChar: ',',
                        allowQuoting: true,
                        allowSparse: false);

    // Use first line of dataset as model input
    // You can replace this with new test data (hardcoded or from end-user application)
    var testDataList = _mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<TInputModel>(dataView, false).ToList();

    List<MulticlassClassificationPrediction> predictionList = new List<MulticlassClassificationPrediction>();
    foreach (var testData in testDataList)
    {

        MulticlassClassificationPrediction result = predEngine.Predict(testData);

        predictionList.Add(result);

    }

    return predictionList;
}
```

Comment: I did but the _mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<TInputModel> wont accept a generic object resulting in compile time error

Comment: I had a typo in my code, which I fixed. The above example compiles just fine locally for me now. Looking at the source code for CreateEnumerable it takes a type where it is class, new(). I hope that helps